# Back button not working as expected in Teams Mobile

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have the MS team's custom tab application for the team's. It is an angular application, it has some internal navigations like navigating from one view to another. When I am sending a notification using the sendActivityNotification API call, it reaches to the mobile app. With the click of the notification, the application loads and it works fine.

But after navigation, if I tap on the back button of the device or (<-) button from the MS team's app header then it behaves like loading the history instead of navigating back to the activity(Feed).

Thanks,
Pratap

Comment: Doesn't it look more like a bug you may want to report to Microsoft Teams team?

Comment: There is already bug raised for the same. We will let you know if there is any update on it.